# Connecting Excel spreadsheet with Google maps while using VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have found a code on which helps me export both travel time and a distance between 2 locations from Google Maps, while using Excel spreadsheet.

It works fine, but one thing I am missing is an opportunity to add an in-between point. Do you think it is doable to modify the code so I could have 3th cell with in-between point?

Please find code below:

```
' Usage :
' GetGoogleTravelTime (strFrom, strTo) returns a string containing journey duration : hh:mm
' GetGoogleDistance (strFrom, strTo) returns a string containing journey distance in either miles or km (as defined by strUnits)
' GetGoogleDirections (strFrom, strTo) returns a string containing the directions
'
' where strFrom/To are address search terms recognisable by Google
' i.e. Postcode, address etc.
'
' by Desmond Oshiwambo

Const strUnits = "metric" ' imperial/metric (miles/km)

Function CleanHTML(ByVal strHTML)
'Helper function to clean HTML instructions
Dim strInstrArr1() As String
Dim strInstrArr2() As String
Dim s As Integer

strInstrArr1 = Split(strHTML, "<")
For s = LBound(strInstrArr1) To UBound(strInstrArr1)
   strInstrArr2 = Split(strInstrArr1(s), ">")
   If UBound(strInstrArr2) > 0 Then
        strInstrArr1(s) = strInstrArr2(1)
   Else
        strInstrArr1(s) = strInstrArr2(0)
   End If
Next

CleanHTML = Join(strInstrArr1)
End Function

Public Function formatGoogleTime(ByVal lngSeconds As Double)
'Helper function. Google returns the time in seconds, so this converts it into time format hh:mm

Dim lngMinutes As Long
Dim lngHours As Long

lngMinutes = Fix(lngSeconds / 60)
lngHours = Fix(lngMinutes / 60)
lngMinutes = lngMinutes - (lngHours * 60)

formatGoogleTime = Format(lngHours, "00") & ":" & Format(lngMinutes, "00")
End Function




Function gglDirectionsResponse(ByVal strStartLocation, ByVal strEndLocation, ByRef strTravelTime, ByRef strDistance, ByRef strInstructions, Optional ByRef strError = "") As Boolean
On Error GoTo errorHandler
' Helper function to request and process XML generated by Google Maps.

Dim strURL As String
Dim objXMLHttp As Object
Dim objDOMDocument As Object
Dim nodeRoute As Object
Dim lngDistance As Long

Set objXMLHttp = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
Set objDOMDocument = CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument.6.0")

strStartLocation = Replace(strStartLocation, " ", "+")
strEndLocation = Replace(strEndLocation, " ", "+")

strURL = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/xml" & _
            "?origin=" & strStartLocation & _
            "&destination=" & strEndLocation & _
            "&sensor=false" & _
            "&units=" & strUnits   'Sensor field is required by google and indicates whether a Geo-sensor is being used by the device making the request

'Send XML request
With objXMLHttp
    .Open "GET", strURL, False
    .setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-URLEncoded"
    .Send
    objDOMDocument.LoadXML .ResponseText
End With

With objDOMDocument
    If .SelectSingleNode("//status").Text = "OK" Then
        'Get Distance
        lngDistance = .SelectSingleNode("/DirectionsResponse/route/leg/distance/value").Text ' Retrieves distance in meters
        Select Case strUnits
            Case "imperial": strDistance = Round(lngDistance * 0.00062137, 1)  'Convert meters to miles
            Case "metric": strDistance = Round(lngDistance / 1000, 1) 'Convert meters to miles
        End Select

        'Get Travel Time
        strTravelTime = .SelectSingleNode("/DirectionsResponse/route/leg/duration/value").Text  'returns in seconds from google
        strTravelTime = formatGoogleTime(strTravelTime) 'converts seconds to hh:mm

        'Get Directions
        For Each nodeRoute In .SelectSingleNode("//route/leg").ChildNodes
            If nodeRoute.BaseName = "step" Then
                strInstructions = strInstructions & nodeRoute.SelectSingleNode("html_instructions").Text & " - " & nodeRoute.SelectSingleNode("distance/text").Text & vbCrLf
            End If
        Next

        strInstructions = CleanHTML(strInstructions) 'Removes MetaTag information from HTML result to convert to plain text.

    Else
        strError = .SelectSingleNode("//status").Text
        GoTo errorHandler
    End If
End With

gglDirectionsResponse = True
GoTo CleanExit

errorHandler:
    If strError = "" Then strError = Err.Description
    strDistance = -1
    strTravelTime = "00:00"
    strInstructions = ""
    gglDirectionsResponse = False

CleanExit:
    Set objDOMDocument = Nothing
    Set objXMLHttp = Nothing

End Function


Function getGoogleTravelTime(ByVal strFrom, ByVal strTo) As String
'Returns the journey time between strFrom and strTo

Dim strTravelTime As String
Dim strDistance As String
Dim strInstructions As String
Dim strError As String

If gglDirectionsResponse(strFrom, strTo, strTravelTime, strDistance, strInstructions, strError) Then
    getGoogleTravelTime = strTravelTime
Else
    getGoogleTravelTime = strError
End If

End Function

Function getGoogleDistance(ByVal strFrom, ByVal strTo) As String
'Returns the distance between strFrom and strTo
'where strFrom/To are address search terms recognisable by Google
'i.e. Postcode, address etc.

Dim strTravelTime As String
Dim strDistance As String
Dim strError As String
Dim strInstructions As String

If gglDirectionsResponse(strFrom, strTo, strTravelTime, strDistance, strInstructions, strError) Then
    getGoogleDistance = strDistance
Else
    getGoogleDistance = strError
End If

End Function

Function getGoogleDirections(ByVal strFrom, ByVal strTo) As String
'Returns the directions between strFrom and strTo
'where strFrom/To are address search terms recognisable by Google
'i.e. Postcode, address etc.

Dim strTravelTime As String
Dim strDistance As String
Dim strError As String
Dim strInstructions As String

If gglDirectionsResponse(strFrom, strTo, strTravelTime, strDistance, strInstructions, strError) Then
    getGoogleDirections = strInstructions
Else
    getGoogleDirections = strError
End If

End Function
```

Thank you,
Przemek

Comment: Could you give some example inputs to work with i.e. locations, strFrom, strTo, strTravelTime, strDistance, strInstructions, strError ...... ?

Comment: @QHarr will do, as soon I get access to the spreadsheet. The idea of adding 3rd point was to calculate route always the way I want as Google Maps might show the distance differently depending on the time of a day.